# C# youtube video downloader console app - not downloading videos

Tags: c#, youtube

I am trying to implement a program that will download video files from youtube. I have written this small windows console app that has two files.

Downloader.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VideoLibrary;
using System.IO;

namespace AsyncAwait
{
    public class Downloader
    {

        public Task DownloadFilesAsync()
        {
            var tasks2 = new Func<Task>[]
            {
                 () => DownloadYoutubeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGxgnH8y2NM"),
                 () => DownloadYoutubeVideo("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNQxxpM1yOs"),
            };
            return Task.WhenAll(tasks2.Select(task => task()).ToArray());
        }

        private void SaveVideoToDisk(string link)
        {
            var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
            var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
            File.WriteAllBytes(@"\Users\KarthikS\Desktop" + video.FullName, video.GetBytes());
        }

        public async Task DownloadYoutubeVideo(string link)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => SaveVideoToDisk(link));
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Downloader d = new Downloader();
        d.DownloadFilesAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("finished");            
    }
}
```

I am using [libvideo](https://github.com/i3arnon/libvideo) to download youtube videos. The program seems to run successfully. But somehow I don't see any file where I expect the file to be created. What am I missing or doing wrong?

I have printed out Number of bytes and `video.FullName`

```
Number of Bytes   82019554 full name                                    Introduction - Django Web Development with Python 1 - YouTube.mp4
Number of Bytes  105567310 full name                              Practical Machine Learning Tutorial with Python Intro p.1 - YouTube.mp4
```

Comment: What are the values of `video.FullName`? I highly doubt this actually runs successfully and the files don't get created

Comment: Also, you don't need, at all, to use `Func<Task>[]`, just `Task[]` would be enough

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto  - please see the update. The names seems to be correct.

Comment: `@"\Users\KarthikS\Desktop" + video.FullName` will give you `@"\Users\KarthikS\Desktop+video.FullName`, so you will not find anything in Desktop but rather under `Karthiks` folder

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but for those who may still be encountering this issue, I conducted some research and made a few slight adjustments to resolve it successfully.

```
private void SaveVideoToDisk(string link)
    {
        var youTube = YouTube.Default; // starting point for YouTube actions
        var video = youTube.GetVideo(link); // gets a Video object with info about the video
        string destinationPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads", video.FullName);
        File.WriteAllBytes(destinationPath, video.GetBytes());
    }
```